# Unresolved External Symbol with Template Function Only When Used

Tags: c++, templates, unresolved-external

I have been getting the :unresolved external symbol "public static int __cdecl Memory::Read (unsigned __int64,unsigned __int64_" for my declaration of a template function "Read"

It is defined in a class known as "memory" with the header file:

```
#ifndef MEMORY_H
#define MEMORY_H

#include <string>
#include "DataFuncs.h"

using namespace std;

  class Memory {

    public:
        template <typename type>
        static type Read(DWORD64 Address, SIZE_T size);
        static bool Write(DWORD64 Address, uintptr_t Value, SIZE_T size);       
  };

#endif
```

Its .cpp definition is the following:

```
#include "Memory.h"

template <typename type>
type Memory::Read(DWORD64 Address, SIZE_T size) {
    return Data.Read<type>(Process_ID, Address, size);
}

bool Memory::Write(DWORD64 Address, uintptr_t Value, SIZE_T size) {

    if (Data.Write(Address, Value, size))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

The error does not occur until it is actually used in a different file. Its implementation is as follows:

```
#include "Memory.h"
#include "Special_Functions.h"

__int32 Special_Functions::Test(){

    __int32 x = Memory::Read<__int32>(0x20302, sizeof(__int32));
    return x;
}
```

If I take away the `Memory::Read<__int32>(0x20302, sizeof(__int32));` line and just type `return 53` then no compiling problems occur. Any idea why and how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: You need to define (not just declare) the template functions in the header

Comment: Templates must be implemented in headers. The compiler needs to see the actual implementation at the point where the template is instantiated.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks!

Comment: Strictly saying, not *must*, but *should*. It's possible to hide implementation into a .cpp, but you'd have to list all types this template has to work with in the same .cpp.